# Does ReactJS create the .js file for the web too?

Tags: javascript, forms, reactjs

I've never used react js and I have only dabbled with node's 'hello world' program.

I'm wondering if react works in such a way that if, say you add an `<input type="text" />` tag, when you submit the form will `react` automatically handle the return of the data or do you need to separately write a client side `.js` file to handle the `ajax` data send to server?

**Bonus**: What is that type of framework called where it creates the two-way interaction automatically?

Apologies for what may be perceived as a basic question, but my beginner level comprehension of javascript hasn't completely got to grips with understanding what the docs actually mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope -- React is just a framework.

If you want to build a 'consolidated' javascript file that contains everything you need for your website, take a look at tools like [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/) (or even better:  [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app))

Form data is is submitted depending on how you structure your form, and that process is dictated a bit [by HTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form) and a bit by [your custom javascript](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html).

To send AJAX based data, take a look at the ['fetch' API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API).

To manage the interaction between React, the data you're rendering, and other systems (like your server) take a look at [Flux](https://facebook.github.io/flux/) or [Redux](http://redux.js.org/).

Comment: Thanks @Dan I think it's flux/redux I'm looking for.

Comment: TY :-) Defo inline with what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

It really depend on how you write your application. React framework just render the "**View**" of your application.

Is you use a basical `<form></form>` with action the browser will automatically send the data into the "`action`" url attribute.

But you can just simulate a send of your form into a `service`/`server`/`fake treatment` and manage your `return` statement.

Answer (score 0):

Well I never used React but, it's a javascript framework that has the same basic structure that Angular and Vue.  Well REACT has directives that you can handle the data to send from the view into the component.js. If you want to send data to server you need to use libraries like 'axios' that you can import into you component and use it.